# Foreground/background/closed apps: How to handle SMS texts in each state

Tags: android

I've read countless StackOverflow posts, answers and the Android documentation. Yet. I *still* can't wrap my head around how to achieve the following.

I wish to make an app, the does something when a new SMS text is received, regardless, if the app itself, is in the foreground (user is currently in the app using it), is in the background (user switched to another app but the app is still open so to speak) *or* closed (user has for example restarted the phone and not opened the app since restart).

I have a broadcast receiver with permissions, but the app only works if the app is in the foreground or the background. If the app is closed, it does not do anything when a SMS is received.

The term *background app*, "long running background service" etc. in android terminology is confusing and is probably the reason why I haven't figured out what it is I am looking for. Perhaps if someone could explain the three states proper naming or explain how to do what I wish to achieve that would be dandy!

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="10000"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>

        <receiver 
            android:name="io.basickarl.passer.HandleSMS" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What API level are you encountering the issue on and how do you declare the receiver? From my experience granting `RECEIVE_SMS` and manifest receiver worked just fine on android 8 or less, but on android 10 they messed up with permissions yet again so maybe it affects you? See https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/runtime_perms#hardRestrictions

Comment: @Pawel My current phone is on Android 9. I did hear things about 10 as you stated, don't know too much though.

Comment: @Pawel I pasted my entire Manifest!

Comment: @Pawel I'll try something, I'll try different versions of Android on the emulator, see if I see  and differences, didn't think of that.